# Call image path in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

If my code is laid out like so,

```
<div data-page-index="1" class="active">
    <img src="foo.png" />
</div>
```

how do I set a variable to the image path if i only have the div class, for example

```
var image1 = $('.active').find(img);
```

so I can append that image whenever neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `src` attribute from, in this case the first instance of, your image.

```
var image1 = $(".active").children("img").eq(0).attr("src");
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Caufc/)

Comment: You could set it to `$(".active img").eq(0).attr("src")` either. That way, you could have another element wrapping the img without breaking it.

Comment: thank you! still in a massive learning curve atm! can i ask, was this a bad question to ask to have been down voted?

Comment: @TimWilkinson not sure why you got the down vote really, there's clearly a question there and you provided existing code examples. You perhaps could have elaborated on your usage scenario more, but that's just nit-picking. There are a lot of good sources for jQuery help on the net - try http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp